# Header overlapping with body in partner ledger report

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, qweb

In the partner ledger report,Header is overlapping with body in the PDF report.In the header I have added company name and address this is overlapping with table data(thead data)

```
<template id="report_mypartnerledger" inherit_id="account.report_partnerledger">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']" position="replace">
            <div class="page">
                <h2 align="center">Party Ledger</h2>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>Period:</strong>
                    <p>
                        <p t-if="data['form']['filter'] == 'filter_period'">
                            Start Date: <span t-esc="get_start_period(data)"/><br/>
                            End Date: <span t-esc="get_end_period(data)"/>
                        </p>
                        <p t-if="data['form']['filter'] == 'filter_date'">
                            Start Date: <span t-esc="formatLang(get_start_date(data), date=True)"/><br />
                            End Date: <span t-esc="formatLang(get_end_date(data), date=True)"/>
                        </p>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <p style="float:right;margin:0;padding:0">
                    <b>Date:</b><span t-usertime="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %p" />
                </p><br></br><br></br>
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Document</th>
                            <th>Invoice</th>
                            <th>Debit</th>
                            <th>Credit</th>
                            <th>Balance</th>
                            <th t-if="amount_currency">Currency</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                     ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Technical -> Reports -> Reports, select your report from there, if no paper format , then add a paper format for the report by opening it.
Then go back to Settings -> Technical -> Reports -> Paper formats, select the corresponding paper format, then adjust its top margin, header spacing etc